# Libm has no trigonometric functions

Tags: c, embedded, gnu, libm

The libmath on a particular embedded system does not have functions like `sin` and `cos` due to missing fp-operation unit.

Is there some library around that provides the functions via look-up tables? I do not actually need 100% reliable values.

Comment: which embedded system exactly are we talking about? TI's DSPs have sin function implemented as a lookup table

Comment: Plenty standard libraries for embedded targets without an FPU include a complete standard math library using *software floating point* arithmetic - even for 8 bit targets. The performance hit can be relatively high, but whether that is an issue is dependent on the application and it is not normally a decision that the tool vendor could or should make.  What is your target and toolchain?  GNU libm certainly includes these functions so your library is either not that or a modified implementation.  You may find that they are merely omitted or conditional compiled out in the header file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the needed requirements for speed and precision, maybe you could create the functions needed by a simple lookup table, by writing a program to create the lookup table.  Or use [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC).

Comment: sounds good, but there is no "out of the box" solution constructing such tables?

Comment: @Stasik: Really?  It is not that hard.  If you don't want to write code, use a spreadsheet, output as a CSV file, then copy and paste the comma separated values between initialiser braces `{...}` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

A better method for targets without hardware floating point is perhaps to use fixed-point and the CORDIC algorithm.

Anthony Williams' [fixed-point maths library](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/news/optimizing-applications-with-fixed-point-arithmetic.html) provides a complete analogue of the standard maths library for a `fixed` data type that is typically around 5 times faster than *software floating-point* on the same target. It is a C++ library, but so long as your compiler supports C++ that should not be a problem even if the rest of your code does not use C++ specific features.  For the most part all you need to do to port code to use this library is to replace math.h with fixed.hpp and replace the type keywords `float` and `double` with the `fixed` type.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have libraries for your system providing you sin/cos functions, or a lookup tables in memory, you can create one very easily.

Next matlab function will provide you `sin(x)` ([0,2*pi] range with 2*pi/100 step) in a c header `myheader.h` :

```
step=2*pi/100;
x=[0:step:2*pi];
y=floor(0.5 * 65535 * sin(x));

fd=fopen('myheader.h','wt');
fprintf(fd,'int16_t y[%d]={%g',length(y),y(1));
fprintf(fd,',\n %.9g',y(2:end));
fprintf(fd,'};\n');
fclose(fd);
```

---

The header looks like this :

```
int16_t y[101]={0,
 2057,
 4107,
 6140,
 8149,
 10126,
 12063,
 13952,
 15786,
 17558,
 19260,
 20887,
 22431,
 23886,
 25248,
 26509,
 27667,
 28714,
 29649,
 30466,
 31164,
 31738,
 32187,
 32509,
 32703,
 32767,
 32703,
 32509,
 32187,
 31738,
 31164,
 30466,
 29649,
 28714,
 27667,
 26509,
 25248,
 23886,
 22431,
 20887,
 19260,
 17558,
 15786,
 13952,
 12063,
 10126,
 8149,
 6140,
 4107,
 2057,
 -0,
 -2057,
 -4107,
 -6140,
 -8149,
 -10126,
 -12063,
 -13952,
 -15786,
 -17558,
 -19260,
 -20887,
 -22431,
 -23886,
 -25248,
 -26509,
 -27667,
 -28714,
 -29649,
 -30466,
 -31164,
 -31738,
 -32187,
 -32509,
 -32703,
 -32768,
 -32703,
 -32509,
 -32187,
 -31738,
 -31164,
 -30466,
 -29649,
 -28714,
 -27667,
 -26509,
 -25248,
 -23886,
 -22431,
 -20887,
 -19260,
 -17558,
 -15786,
 -13952,
 -12063,
 -10126,
 -8149,
 -6140,
 -4107,
 -2057,
 -0};
```

Comment: Maybe you could post the output of this?  I don't have matlab, as I expect is common.

Comment: @wallyk octave is free. Anyway, I edited the question

Comment: If there's no FPU on the target platform, a more suitable way would be to scale these with an integer (and to round them).

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen right. fixed it

Comment: While at it, try int16_t for -xxxx (and notice there's no +32768)

Comment: @wallyk:  You never needed Matlab or Octave (or SciLab or FreeMAT for that matter) to generate the table, you could as easily have written the generator in C (to run on the PC not the target obviously).

Comment: It more memory efficient to generate a table for one quadrant only; values in the other three quadrants can be determined arithmetically from values in the first as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table#Computing_sines).  You can then have either a smaller table, or greater precision.

Answer (score 0):

Jack Ganssle has an excellent article on optimising trig for embedded systems:

http://www.ganssle.com/approx/approx.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to provide such an library, as the are too many design choices and parametrizations compared to the difficulty of writing an own. I mean none of these are very difficult, but can't be provided as fits-for-all solution.

- the parameters:

  - argument of sin/cos == (unsigned) vs (signed)
  - short,int,float, fixed point
  - range: limited (mod pi, mod 2pi)
  - is the argument radians, degrees or something else (e.g. 2pi==65536==0)
- the values

  - float vs. fixed point vs. scaled integer
  - 1st quadrant only, complete or extended range (no modulo reduction of argument needed)
  - both sines & cosines, or just sine
- requirements

  - code size
  - data size
  - execution speed

    - "constant" vs.
    - a lot of variation allowed
  - precision

    - minimize some least square metric
    - minimize some maximum error
    - minimize 1 - sin(x)^2 - cos(x)^2 error
- method

  - direct a=LUT[b]
  - mirroring depending on quadrant: a=sign(b)*LUT[ b ^ mirror(b)]; // conceptual formula
  - CORDIC
  - 3rd or 5th degree Taylor polynomial
  - added (angular) precision using two LUT tables LUTA(x)=sin(x); LUTB(x)=sin(x/256) and formula for sum of angles